# Barrier and image transition

Tags: vulkan

I am wondering why we usually (from Vulkan tutorial and Sascha Willems example) the barrier on the top of pipeline.

If I am reasoning like a producer and consumer (for mipmap creation for example), I have both in src and dst stage the "flag" "TRANSFER_BIT".
So, if I am using the same stage for src and dst, the barrier should happend immediatly, which is the same case if I am using TOP_OF_PIPE flag?

Am I right?

Comment: It's not clear what having the same stage for src and dst has to do with how quickly the barrier executes. I don't understand what it is you believe you understand about Vulkan pipeline barriers.

Comment: The goal of the stageflags in barriers is primarily to ensure a execution dependency between users of a resource.

Comment: @NicolBolas
krOoze explains me in more details what I did not understand before.

To be simple, I do not understand why Sascha Willems use TOP_OF_PIPE for layout transition when it generates mipmaps.
To me, the "correct way" should be to use src = dst = TRANSFER_BIT...
Maybe I miss some details about the "mask" inside the "vkImageMemoryBarrier"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question, but hopefully I will cover it explaining barriers.

`src=TOP_OF_PIPE` or `dst=BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` make a non-blocking barrier (effectivelly being only a half of a Memory Dependency and no Execution Dependency). Is that what you mean by "immediatelly happening" barrier?

`dst=TOP_OF_PIPE` or `src=BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` is supposed to be all-blocking barrier (at least I often see it in examples and tutorials). I am not so clear about that from the spec (especially if Memory Dependency needs to be there too) and `ALL_COMMANDS` (or `|`ing specific stages) seem to be a better replacement.

(BTW I have written about [my peeve](https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/13238-Pipeline-stage-enum-enhancement-proposition) with that API design.)

Generally as for Execution Dependency what the barriers do is: they make sure `srcStage` of all the commands recorded before the barrier is finished before `dstStage` of any of the commands recorded after the barrier started.
(The above special cases should be consistent with that description too.)

So, that being said, `TOP_OF_PIPE` does not seem like a suitable replacement for `TRANSFER`. It would either not perform its intended function at all or be inefficient (based on the descriptions above).

Having `srcStage==dstStage` has no special meaning. Using `TRANSFER` in that case means `TRANSFER` stage of previously recorded commands finished before `TRANSFER` stage of commands recorded after the barrier.

Comment: So, going that way, why some examples (like Sascha Willems ones) use TOP_OF_PIPE and not transfer?
I have a src and dst access in image memory barrier. So does it mean that even if the transfer is not finished, the few that are transfered is "visible"? 
But in this case, the code given by Sascha should be wrong? Or I miss something?

For mipmap generation, do you advice to use src = dst = TRANSFER?

Comment: Lazy implementation (just attempt at an generalized all blocking barrier that can be easily reused everywhere) and inertia (Many early examples had it that way.). @SashaWillems had one of the first examples and the most complete set of them (I swear that guy is a legion). If you see it in many tutorials, it is because they still draw inspiration from him.

Comment: Okay thanks, so it is only to be "more readable" that he does that, but in "robust implementation", I should use transfer bit ??

Comment: PS depends what you mean by mip-map generation. If the common `for(){cmdBlit}` thing then `src = dst = TRANSFER` seem like a good idea.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Yeah, it is a readability, complex engine flexibility and coding effort VS low-levelness and performance thing. You can just make one `src=dst=ALL_COMMANDS` (AIS many use to my disliking `src=BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` + `dst=TOP_OF_PIPE` to achieve the same) barrier and throw it everywhere instead of one tailored to the situation at (potential) cost of performance. Code error is always possibility too (hard to tell without you providing exact code you talk about)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot !
But what do you mean by "if it is the common for(){cmdBlit}"???
There is another way to build mipmapping through GPU?
Maybe you mean to do it on the CPU?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127338/discussion-between-antoine-morrier-and-krooze).